# Slidingmenu using fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, slidingmenu

I am using the com.slidingmenu.lib library.

I have my sliding menu represented by a fragment. I am struggling to see how the fragment in the sliding menu can communicate with the activity that is hosting the sliding menu.

How does this work? I suspect I need some form of listener but can not work out this this would work.

Comment: fragments are part of that fragmentactivity.so u can make them communicate with each other.so kindly describe what exactly do u want to perform ?

Answer (score 0):

The sliding menu is a fragment like any other.

Call getActivity to get a reference to the host activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by

1) Creating a custom java interface let say InterfaceX which can have methods specific to your `Fragment` and making the `Activity` to implement that interface and provide definitions to methods of that interface in your Activity.

2) Cast the `Activity` that is passed into `onAttach()` (You need to override the fragments `onAttach()` method) to InterfaceX.

3) You can call methods of InterfaceX using it's global reference variable.

A complete example and sample code is provided [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity).

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I am using this on my fragmet ;)

```
getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.main);
SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(getActivity());
menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
menu.attachToActivity(getActivity(), SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the method onAttach() in your fragment (the slidingMenu) and get the reference to the activity it is attached to. When you get the activity then you should downcast the reference to your specific class (the name of the activity that extends Activity)in order to be able to call any public method you have declared in the Activity.

Example:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
     // This activity has the sliding menu attached

     public void methodX(){// Do your stuff}
}

class MyFragment extends Fragment{

   MyActivity parent;
   @Overide
   public void onAttach(Activity a){
      super.onAttach(a)
      parent = (MyActivity) a;
      a.methodX();
   }
}
```